# Javascript: SyntaxError: missing variable name for "$(this).hasClass"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to customize an existing function, adding a line that will check if the element has a class.

Note: The lines ending by a `,` were here in the original function, which was working perfectly before I add the `hasClass` detection.

```
function SomeFunction() {
var items = $('.some-class');


items.each(function () {
  var item = $(this),

    children = $(this).find('.content-item'),
    childrenLength  = $(this).find('.content-item').length,
    itemDelayCounter = 0,

    if( $(this).hasClass('some-other-class') ) {
      itemWidth = "100%",
    } else {
      itemWidth = "50%",
    }

    thisDraggableWrapper = item.parent(),
    draggableOffset = thisDraggableWrapper.offset(),
    box = {
      x1: draggableOffset.left + (thisDraggableWrapper.outerWidth() - itemWidth),
      y1: draggableOffset.top + (thisDraggableWrapper.outerHeight() - item.outerHeight()),
      x2: draggableOffset.left,
      y2: draggableOffset.top
    };

  item.draggable({
    containment: [box.x1 + 120, box.y1, box.x2, box.y2 ],
    axis: "x"
  });

  item.appear(function() {
    $(this).css({'width': itemWidth, 'transition': childrenLength*1.3 + 's', 'pointer-events': 'none'});
    children.each(function() {
      itemDelayCounter+=0.6;
      $(this).css({'opacity': '1', 'transition': '.5s ' + itemDelayCounter + 's', 'transform': 'translateX(-66px) translateY(0)'});
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      item.css({'transition': '', 'pointer-events': 'auto'});
      children.each(function() {
        $(this).css({'transition': ''});
      });
    }, 3500);
  }, {accX: 0, accY: 50});
});
```

}

I got the following error on Firefox:
`SyntaxError: missing variable name` on the line with "hasClass".
and on Chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` on the same line.

If I do what was recommended here, and replace all the `,` by `;` I also got an error which is :
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'` on line `itemWidth = "100%";`

I am a bit confused, because indeed the lines should end by a `;` but it seems that in the case the function is listing a set of variables that are reused in inner functions, because we can notice that thoses variables are used again here (just my supposition).

Or it is "another" way of writing JS.. I don't know!

Comment: Your `var` declaration ends with a comma instead of a semicolon. In fact you seem to be using `,` in other places that should be `;` instead.

Comment: All your line endings are with comma instead of semicolon

Comment: Voting to close: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys.
Yes I agree that the lines shoud end by `;` and not `,`
But those first lines actually come from the original function that I am editing, and the code was working fine until I modify it !

So I really wonder why this original code has commas for ending line ..

@Quentin you are concluding things a bit fast IMO, this is not a simple typo, as I said the commas were here orginaly and the code was working fine

Comment: @Pointy and other voters
Could you please vote to re-open the question please ?

I edited the post, posting the whole function and explaining all the errors.
This sounds to be a strange case to me, and not just a noob syntax error.

Thank you very much

Comment: @SimonMo the updated code *still has the exact same error*.  Your initial `var` declaration declares 4 variables and it ends with a `,` before that `if`. The complaint has nothing to do with `$(this)`.

Comment: And you get the error about `itemWidth` because that symbol is not declared anywhere.

Comment: If the change you made to the original code is that `if` statement around the declaration of `itemWidth`, then that is the problem. You cannot drop an `if` statement into the middle of a list of variables being declared in a `var` statement.

Comment: @Pointy so I don't understand why you are voting to close the issue.

Declaring `ItemWidth`, closing var declaration with `;` still raises errors

Comment: Your code has an very simple syntax error. You're trying to add that `if` statement around `itemWidth`, right? You can't do it that way; you have to let `itemWidth` be declared the way it was in the original code, and then add your `if` statement after the end of the list of declared variables.

Comment: And I've already voted to re-open.

Comment: Really I don't understand, isn't this supposed to be a website to *HELP PEOPLE SOLVING PROBLEMS WITH CODE* ?

I feel like you come here saying OK you're a big noob, you are not helping at all, and you are voting to close the question ... OK thanks man ..

Comment: I am trying pretty hard to help you solve the problem; I don't know how much more I can do so in fact. I've told you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I understand better now @Pointy
That's what I was expecting from StackOverflow, having people helping me :) Too bad we had to argue in comments to have this results, having a question closed like this is a bad feeling ;)
Anyway thanks, from your last comments now everything is more clear to me.

Comment: Yes indeed, we were just commenting at the same time so some of my comments came before I could read all your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Command endings should be with `;` not `,`

```
function SomeFunction() {
var items = $('.some-class');


items.each(function () {
  var item = $(this);
  option1 = "some value";
  option2 = "some value";


    if( $(this).hasClass('some-other-class') ) {
      ItemWidth = "100%";
    } else {
      ItemWidth = "50%";
    }
```

Other problems that you have in your code is that you aren't declaring the variables.
*If they are declared in other place, maybe globally, please put the code where you declare then.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's the not the cause of the problem because commas were here originally, I edited my question posting the whole function

Comment: @SimonMo could you please update your question and put the whole error, with all the stack?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.
I already edited the original question, putting the whole function.

About the stack, it's for wordpress.. (nobody is perfect..!)
About the errors, I don't have more information, FF says `SyntaxError: missing variable name` and chrome says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Comment: befero the `if` statement, there is `itemDelayCounter = 0,` wichs end with `,`. That's is causing the `Unexpected token if`. Change all `,` to `;` and see what happens

Comment: If I do your change, I now got another error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','`

Comment: and replacing  `itemWidth = "100%",` by `itemWidth = "100%";` does : `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'`

looks like it's never happy either with `,` or with `;`

Comment: @SimonMo you should change all `,` in your code, and change you question. Putting the errors here in the comments isn't good, you should place then in your question